# Bad password error while extracting a zip from python zipfile

Tags: python-3.x, extract, zip

I am trying a straight forward code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

password = '1sS34nConn3ryTh3B3st007?'

zip_file = 'file.zip'
with ZipFile(zip_file) as zf:
     zf.extractall(pwd=bytes(password,'utf-8'))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1524, in extractall
    self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1577, in _extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1446, in open
    raise RuntimeError("Bad password for file %r" % name)
RuntimeError: Bad password for file <ZipInfo filename='file.csv' compress_type=99 file_size=272074 compress_size=60230>
```

It works perfectly fine when I am extracting it on windows using either 7z or winrar. py7zr also gives error.

Comment: What encryption system is the zip file using? Newer Zip files use AES-256 which older zip libraries can't handle.

Comment: I am not sure of that, is there a way to find out from the file? Also if it is AES-256 which I am assuming it is then what should be the python library and code to unzip it?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to encrypt a file from 7z Ui on Windows with your password.
After I ran this script:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

password = '1sS34nConn3ryTh3B3st007?'

zip_file = 'file.zip'
zf = ZipFile(self.archive_name, 'r')
zf.setpassword(bytes(password,"utf-8"))
zf.extractall(path=".")
```

No issue. Can you try as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pyzipper module instead of zipfile, because of the newer AES-256 encoding.